# Choice between thread: time expired and user input

Tags: c++, multithreading, getline

I'm writing a simple function that, when called, allows to execute 2 different actions (exclusive).

So there are two threads. `User_choice` waits until the user inserts an input and the `Time_choice` waits until time expires.

The `choice_done` shared var says that, if true, one thread has already started and blocking (it doesn't do anything!) the other one; Whereas `thread_done` says, if true, that thread (it doesn't matter which) has already finished, so `func()` waits until one thread finishes.

Here is the code.
The `func` procedure will be called more times during the program execution.

The various `user_choice` thread will be waiting forever on `getline`! Is it a problem? What if, after four times the program will call `func()` and the user doesn't insert anything, the 5th time the user inserts "yes"?
Will every `user_choice` thread continue the execution?? How can I **kill** the waiting thread? Are there other solutions?

How can I wait inside `func()` that a thread sets `thread_done` to true?

```
bool choice_done = false;
bool thread_done = false;

void func(){
   boost::thread t1(boost::bind( time_choice() ));
   boost::thread t2(boost::bind( user_choice() ));

   //whait untile thread_done == true
   do something...
}

// Time choice thread
void time_choice(){

    sleep(5);

    if(choice_done == false){

        printf("Automatic choice\n");
        choice_done == true;

        do something...

        thread_done = true;
    } 
}


// User choice thread
void user_choice(){        

    printf("Start emergency procedure?\n");

    string tmp;
    getline(cin, tmp);

    if((tmp.compare("yes") == 0) && (choice_done == false)){

        printf("Manual choice\n");
        choice_done == true;

        do something... 

        thread_done = true;           
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having to create a thread for a timer is generally a sign of sub-optimal design. It does not scale well (imagine thousands of timers) and the code gets multi-threaded and more complex for no good reason. Also, [`sleep` is not thread-safe on Linux](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html).

Just use one thread with [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pselect.html) and a timeout. `select` will wait on `STDIN_FILENO` for user input and timeout simultaneously.

Or, better, use a 3rd-party event-demultiplexing library, like [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: @gepeppe You do. When `STDIN_FILENO` is ready for read, reading from it won't block (but you still need to use non-blocking I/O to read the entire line).